# multi switch onchange checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Several switch buttons for the form are written in **JavaScript** and **laravel**. I want to save in the database.

my blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.settings.post') }}" method="POST">

<label class="switch">
<input class="id-target" onchange="click_switch(this)" value="{{ $post }}" name="post" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" @if($post == 'on') checked="" @endif>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
<input class="id-target" onchange="click_switch(this)" value="{{ $product }}" name="product" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" @if($product == 'on') checked="" @endif>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
<input class="id-target" onchange="click_switch(this)" value="{{ $course }}" name="course" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" @if($course == 'on') checked="" @endif>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<button class="btn" type="submit">save</button>

</form>

<script>
function click_switch(el){
    if(el.checked){
        $(".id-target").val("on");
    }else{
        $(".id-target").val("");
    }
}
</script>
```

sample:

```
switch 1 : on/off  ---> off
switch 2 : on/off  ---> on
switch 3 : on/off  ---> off
```

When I click the first switch and then I click the save option.
The second switch turns on.

```
switch 1 : on/off  ---> on
switch 2 : on/off  ---> on
switch 3 : on/off  ---> on
```

The problem is that they **save** together.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Post all relevant code/your full attempt (like your PHP code), example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, your `click_switch()` function seems a bit pointless. Just set `on` as value in the input directly. When you post that form, only checkboxes that are checked will be submitted with the form anyway.

Comment: @MEriksson
it is ``$(".id-target").val("on")`` for all input. When I click the first switch and then I click the save option.
The second switch turns on.

Comment: I can see that, but I still don't get what the point of that code is? Please read the links I posted and edit your question. It's _very_ unclear how you want to store those checkboxes, what they are, what the point of your JS is, what you have tried and where you're stuck. We can't help if we don't know what you need help with. We need specifics since we're here to help sort your code out, not to write it all for you (which a proper answer currently would require)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your query is selecting all your buttons, as you’re using a class selector. The fixed JS would look like this.

```js
function click_switch(el){
  el.value = el.checked ? ‘On’ : ‘’
}
```

However, you don’t need JS as `on` is the default value for a checkbox. When checked the value will be `on` and when it is unchecked the value will be an empty. When you set the value attribute on a checkbox it just replace `on` as the checked value. An unchecked input always returns an empty string.